# Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('chempion',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>

Tags: django, reverse

Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '('chempion',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

**as soon as I add function and view to templates I catch this error**

**view.py**

```
def post_detail(request, category_slug, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)

    try:
        next_post = post.get_next_by_date_added()
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        next_post = None

    try:
        previous_post = post.get_previous_by_date_added()
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        previous_post = None

    context = {
        'post': post,
        'next_post': next_post,
        'previous_post': previous_post
    }

    return render(request, 'post_detail.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
  path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', category_detail, name='category_detail'),
```

post detail.html

```
 {% if next_post %}
    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' next_post.slug %}">Next</a>
 {% else %}
    This is the last post!
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Your url expects ***two*** slugs as you can see here `'<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug>/'` but you are passing only one slug...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  that is so? {% url 'post_detail' post.slug  next_post.slug %}

Comment: These url patterns are written by you so you would know better but I would think `category_slug` would imply a slug for a category yes?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you were right thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `post_detail` view requires two slugs: one of slug for the category, and one for the post.

If your `Post` model for example has a `ForeignKey` to the `Category` model, you can reference this with:

```
<a href="{% url 'post_detail' next_post.category.slug next_post.slug %}">Next</a>
```

In your view, you might want to check both the slug for the category *and* for the post, so:

```
def post_detail(request, category_slug, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, category__slug=category_slug, slug=slug)
    # …
```